# Can a library built in standard Linux be used in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, glibc

I wrote a library in latest Linux distribution, which depends on glibc and sockets. I hear that glibc is not supported in Android. Is there a way that I rebuild my code without much modification for Android and let it run? If yes, I will use JNI to call the code.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Android runs with bionic, and doesn't have glibc.

However you can try to build your code with [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and fix the problems on the way to build it.
If you don't use anything glibc specific, it should be fairly easy.

Comment: It is possible to use `glibc` on Android, see for example the following thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1299962. But no doubt using bionic is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "uses glibc".  If it uses non-standard extensions that only glibc implements, then you'll have some trouble.  But Android's libc (called "bionic") supports most of POSIX, so if you aren't doing anything too unusual, it should work.  The best way to find out is to try to build your library with the NDK and see what happens.